# Holomorphic function with real part being $(\Re z)^2$ on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

As in the title I would like to find a holomorphic function $f$ such that $\Re f(z)=(\Re z)^2$ for every $z$ on the unit circle.

Comment: What does Rez mean?

Comment: Do you mean$(\mathrm{Re}(z))^2$?

Comment: real part of a function identity on $\mathbb{C}$ .

Comment: @user1952009 what is $f$?

Comment: Your function. Did you mean $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, or only holomorphic around $|z|=1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x^2+y^2=1,$ then $$x^2 = \text {Re}\left( \frac {(x+iy)^2+1}{2}\right).$$ Thus $f(z)= \dfrac {z^2+1}{2}$ is a solution.

Comment: can you find my mistake ? I don't